# docker-compose postgres volume changes ownership to gitlab-runner

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a very strange problem, and cannot find why this happens. I installed gitlab-runner on my computer a several months ago, maybe a year and didn't use it anymore .

I have a docker-composer.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    #restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./storage:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I create ./storage, a `ls` gives me:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 pierre-emmanuel pierre-emmanuel 4096 jui 31 23:33 storage
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d` , the user is changed to `gitlab-runner` ... I don't understand this AT ALL. It should have never happened.

Here is the `ls` I have:

```
drwx------ 19 gitlab-runner   pierre-emmanuel 4096 jui 31 23:35 storage
```

Now I repeated this and with `ps -aux | grep gitlab` was able to see this:

```
gitlab-+  2404 11.5  0.0  19704  3456 ?        Ss   23:34   0:00 bash /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh postgres
gitlab-+  2514  6.0  0.0  19904  3912 ?        S    23:35   0:00 initdb --username=postgres --pwfile=/dev/fd/63
gitlab-+  2536  0.0  0.0   4280   712 ?        S    23:35   0:00 sh -c "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres" --single -F -O -c search_path=pg_catalog -c exit_on_error=true template1 >/dev/null
gitlab-+  2537  0.0  0.3 281888 28572 ?        R    23:35   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres --single -F -O -c search_path=pg_catalog -c exit_on_error=true template1
```

Then after it stays like this until I call `docker-composer stop`:

```
gitlab-+  2404  0.0  0.2 274528 23304 ?        Ss   23:34   0:00 postgres
gitlab-+  2618  0.0  0.0 274528  3780 ?        Ss   23:35   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process  
gitlab-+  2619  0.0  0.0 274528  5400 ?        Ss   23:35   0:00 postgres: writer process  
gitlab-+  2620  0.0  0.0 274528  3780 ?        Ss   23:35   0:00 postgres: wal writer process  
gitlab-+  2621  0.0  0.0 274956  6252 ?        Ss   23:35   0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process  
gitlab-+  2622  0.0  0.0 129512  2828 ?        Ss   23:35   0:00 postgres: stats collector process
```

My own user and `gitlab-runner` do have the `docker` group, but I can't figure out why this is producing. Do you have any idea ?

EDIT: when I remove the app, remove the volume from docker-compose.yml and re-create the app, the user gitlab-runner is still used to run the container which contains postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes and files are owned by *numeric* user and group IDs.  There's a file, `/etc/passwd`, that maps between user names and user IDs; but the nature of Docker is that each container has its own isolated filesystem space, which means it has its own `/etc/passwd` file.

If you look at [the Docker Hub `postgresql` page](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) there is a link to the image's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/87b15b6c65ba985ac958e7b35ba787422113066e/9.5/Dockerfile) and you can see that includes a command

```sh
RUN useradd ... --uid=999 ... postgres
```

You should be able to verify that the user IDs on your local system and inside the container match up

```sh
grep gitlab-runner /etc/passwd
docker run --rm postgres:9.5 grep postgres /etc/passwd
```

I would expect both of these to show a uid of 999 in the third field.  The files are owned by that uid, but it happens to translate to a different name inside and outside the container.

Comment: Very Interesting ! Do you have any piece of advice to avoid that problem ? Should I rebuild the postgresl container with my own uid or is there a best one ?

Comment: I confirm that both uid are 999, for gitlab-runner on host, and for postgres inside of the postgres container. I hope it happens only with users which have the `docker` group, else it would mean docker can give permissions to a volume folder to any user ....

Comment: It's very common for Docker containers to run as root and they can make arbitrary changes to whatever fraction of the host filesystem is passed in.  Correspondingly, if you can run any `docker` command, it's almost trivial to root the host.

Comment: The goal is to share a volume to get the data in it for backup. The new ownership doesn't let me access it with my user which started the docker. Is there a way to have the right ownership ?

Comment: I found that I should bind mount /etc/passwd to change it. I think it will work, thans for your explanations !

Comment: The thing that I don't understand is why the users inside the docker aren't mapped with another users outside docker. Do you have any advice ?